# Listening or read Quran while naked

Tags: quran, practical-islam, adab, quran-recitation, muslim-practices

Is listening to Quran while naked allowed?

Is reading Quran while naked allowed?

Naked in this case, means, at least there is underwear on.

Please cite authentic reference with answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to do this as it was narrated that there was nothing prevents the prophet from (reciting) Quran except for Janabah:

> لَمْ يَكُنْ يَحْجُبُهُ عَنِ الْقُرْآنِ شَىْءٌ لَيْسَ الْجَنَابَةَ
>
> " Nothing would prevent him from (reciting) Qur'an except Janabah."
>
> Source: http://sunnah.com/urn/1002670

BUT: you should not do that, as you should show respect to Allah and Qur'an as the Messenger of Allah said:

> اللَّهُ أَحَقُّ أَنْ يُسْتَحْيَا مِنْهُ مِنَ النَّاسِ ‏
>
> Allah is more entitled than people that bashfulness should be shown to
>   him.
>
> Source: http://sunnah.com/abudawud/33/9

If you do this as a kind of disrespecting Quran, so, it's haram.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, you're judged by your intentions:

> Allah will not call you to account for thoughtlessness in your oaths, but for the intention in your hearts; and He is Oft-forgiving, Most Forbearing. (Al-Baqara: Verse 225)

Allah (swt) will not bring to account your negligence, rather your intentions. If you read the Quran while you're naked because you want to read the Quran every chance you've, so to memorize it, how can anyone question your intentions and say that you're doing something wrong?

Comment: I feel the justification here maybe, IMHO, a bit far. Because we should, in cases apply, to follow our Prophet's Sunnah. Not sure if the sunnah reading Quran as same as apply to prayer, because if someone did something in worship that has not been done before, Allah will not punish for the extra worship we have done but will punish for the innovation has been made with it. That's why I ask this question. But jazaklahir for the attempt :)

Comment: Even if in the future people read the Quran naked as a cultural practice, and even if that culture was influenced by you, even then, you're not at fault if your intention was good. The Aya is very clear on this matter. Innovation can come to practice thoughtlessly, or through negligence, so once again, you will not be punished for it if your intentions are good. Also, could you please provide reference.

Comment: The site not sure authenticity, but the reference is good inshaAllah. https://www.sayingsofthesalaf.net/will-allah-punish-me-for-praying-bidah/

Comment: Any Hadith that contradicts the Quran is nullified to begin with, putting aside the authenticity.